# Doctrine throw error: "A new entity was found through the relationship" after removing entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Let's say I have two entities, `Project` and `User` with relation.

Project.php

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $creator;
```

When I remove the `User` entity, the `doctrine` leaves the `User` object(without ID) in the `Project` entity. In a normal situation, this is fine but I am using [DomainEvents](https://romaricdrigon.github.io/2019/08/09/domain-events). In this scenario, after removing the User entity, DomainEvent triggers saving some data in the DB and secondary saving data(after removing) throw this error. This happens because of now in the `Project` entity we have the detached(from the `EM`) `User` object without ID.

I thought about a listener, that will remove empty objects in the entity after removing, but I am not sure that is a good variant

What is the best variant for solving this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `onDelete` option doesn't apply a cascade removing.
If you want to do so I think you should have to add the `cascade={"remove"}` option to the ManyToOne.

Try as following :

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $creator;
```

[Removing entity in doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html)

Comment: The project should not be deleted, when deleting the creator, we must set null

Comment: @IhorKostrov any chance you have solved this by now? I'm facing the same issue. I basically need to "orphan" the child entity without deleting it, but when I delete the parent, Doctrine sees it as a new entity through the child -> parent reference.

Comment: @TonyBogdanov as I remember needs to avoid lazy loading of your entities, when you are removing the parent, your child entities shouldn't be loaded to UOW.

Comment: @IhorKostrov yeah, that makes perfect sense, but probably not always possible. Thanks!